# Qual é a diferença de um Hazard estático e dinâmico?

Tags: lógica

Pelo que eu sei um Hazard é um efeito indesejado causado pela deficiência no sistema ou por influências externas. Um hazard em um sistema lógico ocorre quando existe uma modificação no *input* que não resulta em uma mudança do *output*. Mas alguém pode me explicar o que é ou qual a diferença de um Hazard estático e um dinâmico?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definição**

Devido aos atrasos nos componentes eletronicos, um circuito pode originar um 
*glitch*. Um *glitch* é uma variação de curta duração no valor de uma saída, quando não se espera nenhuma variação. Ocorre um *hazard* quando existe a possibilidade de o circuito gerar um *glitch*.

**Hazard estático**

Ocorre um *hazard estático* quando existe a possibilidade de uma saída
sofrer uma transição momentânea em condições em que se esperava que ela se mantivesse inalterada. Isso pode ocorrer quando uma unica entrada da função tem
seu valor alterado e esta mudança causa mudança momentânea na saída da função.

Existem 2 tipos de *Hazard estático*

1. *Hazard* de nível logico 1, que acontece quando a saída da função deveria
   permanecer no nível logico alto, mas passa momentaneamente pelo nível
   logico baixo e depois retorna ao alto.

[image: Static Hazard nivel 1]

2. *Hazard* de nível logico 0, que acontece quando a saída da função deveria 
   permanecer no nível logico baixo, mas passa momentaneamente pelo nível
   logico alto e depois retorna ao baixo.

[image: Static Hazard nivel 0]

**Hazard dinâmico**

Ocorre um *hazard* dinâmico quando for possível uma saída mudar mais do que uma vez, em condições em que se esperava que ela tivesse uma unica transição (de 0 para 1 ou de 1 para 0). Isso ocorre quando uma mudança na entrada da função causa múltiplas mudanças na saída.

Existem 2 tipos de *Hazard dinâmico*

1. A saída da função que deveria sofrer uma unica transição de 0 para 1, mas sofre a transição de 0 para 1 (que deveria ficar estável), depois sofre transição de 1 para 0 e então retorna para 1, ficando estável.
2. A saída da função que deveria sofrer uma unica transição de 1 para 0, mas sofre a transição de 1 para 0 (que deveria ficar estável), depois sofre ´
   transição de 0 para 1 e então retorna para 0, ficando estável.

[image: Dynamic Hazards]

[*Link* de onde copiei a resposta](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~diegomd/Site/UFMG/2Periodo/hazards.pdf)